# ImportError in Django Rest Framework with Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I have develop a simple app to learn Django rest framework and then uploaded it into Google app engine. But each time I try to access my data it shows me "no module name rest_framework". it works ok if I dont use Google App engine and stop working if I use (both local install or deploy the codes). I am using django 1.4 and using Cloud SQL. Can anyone please tell me what might be the problem?

regards
Samin

screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Make sure to copy all external Python modules into your app folder. Specifically, it looks like `rest_framework` is not in your app root dir.

Comment: can you please look into the screenshot please? I am adding them in PYTHONPATH. do I also need to add into app.yaml?

Comment: You can;t just set the python path.. As @alex  said you have to copy the library into your project. There are hundreds of this type of question. No one seems to read the docs, or searches SO.  Whilst the questions out there may not relate to the same library the problems are all the same, not reading the docs, and not copying/linking libraries into your project.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but might help someone else, I was also trying to get a solution for this error then I came across this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27) which has all the thirdparty apps, google app engine support. It doesn't have rest_framework.

So a as a solution you will have to copy the third-party library's pure-Python source code into your application's source code.

here is a solution in [detail](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library).

Hope that helps!